# How to Capture web service output in Developer Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

We have a web service which is creating a record in a database table and gives response/output as "SUCCESS" after successful insertion in SOAP UI

We have developed a Project in Developer Studio and called this webservice using AddressEndPoint, and deployed CAR file on ESB Server

The webservice is calling successfully via ESB and records are inserting in the tables but we are unable to log "SUCCESS" status anywhere we tried to use log mediator after CALL(AddressEndPoint) Mediator but it is not logging webservice response.
**Below is my Source:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationPS"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap11"
                        uri="http://10.1.6.175:9763/services/EslSfaOMSODataService.SOAP11Endpoint/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="full"/>
         <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationMapping.dmc"
                     inputSchema="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationMapping_inputSchema.json"
                     inputType="XML"
                     outputSchema="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationMapping_outputSchema.json"
                     outputType="XML"/>
         <log description="" level="full"/>
         <header name="Authorization"
                 scope="transport"
                 value="Basic cHdjLmV0aXNhbGF0OkZlcmd1c29uMTIz"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap11"
                        uri="https://eere-test.scm.ap1.oraclecloud.com:443/soa-infra/services/default/DooDecompReceiveOrderExternalComposite/ReceiveOrderRequestService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" type="body"/>
            <target property="ReceiveOrderServiceResponseMessage" type="property"/>
         </enrich>
         <log level="custom">
            <property expression="get-property('ReceiveOrderServiceResponseMessage')"
                      name="moidSiddiqui"/>
         </log>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Please elaborate or give a code example.  You should be able to log simply by using <log level="full"/>

Comment: Try enabling wirelogs[1] in the ESB and check whether ESb actually gets the 'SUCCESS' response from the webservice. http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: i enabled wirelogs but it is only log raw response not actual webservice output

Answer (score 1):

I use this property after my call mediator to get the status

```
<log>
  property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Status" 
  expression="get property('axis2','HTTP_SC')"/>
</log>
```

You can find more information here

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/HTTP+Transport+Properties

To obtain the response of the service I use

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" type="body"/>
    <target property="Ouput_Respose_Service" type="property"/>
</enrich>

<log level="custom" separator=",">
     <property expression="get-property('Ouput_Respose_Service')" name="Service_Response"/>
</log>
```

Comment: Alber: i have shared my source in the question, i have added as you suggested, my webservice output name is 'ReceiveOrderServiceResponseMessage' but in carbon.log i got null against the property name

Comment: hi, You have validated that the second service responds ok ?, add a full log after the second call to see the response that brings